# system master page issue with popup dialogs

Tags: master-page

Using the night and day Master Page from the publishing template, I've created a clone with minimal changes e.g top nav with flyouts. 
I wanted to use this new master page also for the system pages, so that browsing throug doclibs would also look nice..

The problem I have is that when I call dialogs such as the file upload, the topnav and other stuff also apear in the dialogs, making them nearly unusable, because the buttons on the bottom disappear.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

Solved. I had the topnav etc. outside the .
Moving the elements inside this div ensures that they are hidden inside the poups.

Edit: And an even more elegant way is adding the css class s4-notdlg to all divs why shouldn't appear in dialogs. This way the divs can be anywhere..

Comment: If you could mark your answer as accepted that be great for people scanning over the questions or searching to see that you found a solution to your problem. Also, please tag with the version of SharePoint that you were using, as this is again valuable to others who may have had the same problem as you.